# How transfer the data of 1 array from an existing 2D array into a new function?

Tags: python

I have this code that I am working on to calculate the stride rate from a kinematic motion analysis app. I am attempting to calculate strides per second. Based on my Stride function I already have I should just have to pull the data from the Stride function into my stride rate (SR) function, but I keep getting zeros in my new array/ output data. I'm a beginner with python and am unsure how to pull 1 array of data out of a 2D array. Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
def SR(demands):
  SR = np.zeros((14,1))
  ST = demands['STRIDE'][:,0]

  for M in range(14, len(ST)):
    SR[M,0] = ((ST[M]-ST[M-1])/(1/30))
  return SR
```

## have also tried

```
def SR(demands):
  SR = np.zeros((14,1))
  ST = demands['STRIDE'][:,0]

  for M in range(0, 14):
     SR[M,0] = ((ST[M]-ST[M-1])/(1/30))
  return SR
```

```py
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

This is the NumPy array output I keep getting. I should be getting strides per second.

```py
15  1458.46
33  -1341.3
51  1438.37
73  -1478.02
88  1319.48
109 -1484.34
125 1406.37
145 -1480.24
161 1481.32
182 -1517.04
200 1409.71
222 -1403.54
238 1485.07
259 -1395.48
```

This is the Stride Function data output that I am attempting to input into my new function. The left column is the frames/ first array, and the right column is just the length of the stride in that frame or second array.

Comment: How are you defining your 2d array you use as input?
Edit: your input is a pandas dataframe? I think it would help if you added this.

Comment: Sorry you will have to clarify what you mean by a pandas dataframe, I have only been dealing with python for 2 weeks and not familiar with how to use it or its terminology.

Comment: pandas is a library, if you are using the library. It isn't native to python so if you don't know what it is you probably aren't using it so don't worry.

Can you try seeing what the input has in it?

Comment: There is an import in the existing call file that imported pandas as pd, if that is what you are referring to?

Comment: yes, it is, pandas uses something called dataframes, which is basically just a table.  can you also tell me what version of python you are using? certain versions round down int to int division. Also, if you are using x/(1/30) it would be the same to just multiply by 30.

Comment: your function works fine, and I can't seem to replicate the problem. Check in how you load the data.

Comment: I am using version 3.7 of python

Comment: How would I check how the data is being loaded?

Comment: print(demands) and make sure it is what you would expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a try

Comment: The function is now running! Thanks for all your Help!